# Wipe ChromeOS drive and start net

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Is there a way to fully wipe the harddrive for a ChromeOS laptop and do a full install of Linux?

I've been playing around with the many different ways for installing linux to a ChromeBook to make it usable but I've started to notice a bunch of SDAx under /dev and really would like to just start new so that I have more free space.

Is there a way to do this?

This is an Acer c720. I do have USB booting available. I have developer mode on and legacy boot enabled as well.

Comment: Can you post the model and describe its hardware complement?  Do you know what boot options it has (can you boot from USB)?

Answer (score 2):

You can clean-install, which resets your computer then installs Linux.

Note: You will need a minimum of 2GB RAM for the 64bit release. If you don’t know how much RAM your computer has, download the 32bit release.

- If you want Ubuntu from the website, click [here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
- If you want to download it via BitTorrent, click [here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

Once downloaded, you will need to burn the Ubuntu ISO image to DVD optical disc.

1.Open your DVD drive and insert the newly burnt Ubuntu ISO disc. If your computer is off, turn it on and open the DVD drive, insert the disc, close the drive, then press and hold the power button until your PC turns off (ignore any on-screen instructions).

2.Reboot or turn on your computer. Most computers will automatically detect the disc in your DVD drive and boot from it, but if you keep booting into your existing operating system (ie. Windows) you will need to access and change the boot menu in your BIOS to make the first boot device your DVD optical drive, hard drive second.

3.Once you have your computer booting from the DVD drive, Ubuntu will load basic services and bring you to the main install screen (see below) which can take a while to show up so allow up to 5 minutes for lower spec computers.

4.Follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for the advice. I have improved my answer.

Comment: Well written answer, but the OP has a Chromebook. The one described in the question has a HDD (typical configuration often has no internal drives, just a removable SD/microSD card for local storage). Unless the OP has an external optical drive or posts that his model contains one, a solution based on one isn't likely to be applicable. A solution based on a pen drive  might be a better bet if the Chromebook is bootable from it (I'm not familiar enough with them to know about the boot options).  Really need to get some feedback from the OP.